# GET/POST method not working to get data from mysql database to html using json

Tags: php, mysql, json, html

I am trying to get data in html page from mysql database using `GET/POST` method with help of `json` and `Jquery`. The scenario is i am taking two value from user interface (`searchtenant.html`) and POST it to `newterms2.html` where `newterms2.html` is getting data from `tenantlistmob2.php` using `JSON`.
My `searchtenant.html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<form action="newterms2.html" method="post">
First Name:<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required="required"/><br /><br />
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required="required"/><br /><br />
<input type="submit" id="save" name="search" value="Search"/>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

My `tenantlistmob2.php` is

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tenanttemp` WHERE `TenantFirstName`='$fname' and `TenantLastName`='$lname'");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tenanttemp`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
 $array[] = array($row['TenantFirstName']);
 }
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

My `newterms2.html` is like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.getJSON("tenantlistmob2.php", function (jsonData) {
            jsonData= eval(jsonData);//get json array
            for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)//iterate over all options
            {
              for ( key in jsonData[i] )//get key => value
              { 
                   var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + jsonData[i][key] + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#getname tbody");
              }
            }

   });

   });
  </script></head>
 <body>
 <form name="index">
 <div id="getname2"></div>
 <div>
 <table id="getname" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the total scenario.If i call `tenantlistmob2.php` directly from `searchtenant.html` using `POST` method it works fine.But i need html page to show the data because i will use this html page for both `android` and `iPhone`. The query (`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tenanttemp");`) works fine and return properly to `newterms2.html`.But when i use `POST`ed data (`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tenanttemp WHERE TenantFirstName='$fname' and TenantLastName='$lname'");`) it works properly in php but not returning data to `newterms2.html` page.

What is the solution? I like to get the data in html page.Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the formdata from searchtenant.html to newterms2.html and not to tenantlistmob2.php.

- jQuery/Javascript can not handle POST data sent to a page.
- jQuery.getJSON uses GET, not POST.

What you need to do is to change newterms2.html into a PHP page that can use the POST data from searchtenant.html and use it for the ajaxrequest.

**Javascriptchanges in newterms2.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'tenantlistmob2.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: <?php echo 'fname='.$_POST['fname'].'&lname='.$_POST['lname']; ?>,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(jsonData){
                jsonData = eval(jsonData); //get json array
                for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)//iterate over all options
                {
                    for ( key in jsonData[i] )//get key => value
                    { 
                        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + jsonData[i][key] + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                        $(tblRow).appendTo("#getname tbody");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

That should do the trick.